# How to get web api request data (Get,Post,Put and Delete) from the raw request itself not receiving it in a method parameters

Tags: httprequest, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api, httpcontext

I am using **WorkContext** that contains information about the current request such as logged-in user, current culture and so on;
My question is i want to Interrogates **HttpContext.Current** to get data from request;(Method Body; i already know how to get it from query string) i mean i want to get Jason Data that is passed when the user make the request in case of Get,Post,Put and Delete requests; note i want to get data from raw url **HttpContext.Current.Request** not receive data in a method paraemeter as i want to get generic data that is common on all methods

Comment: any help for my question

Answer (score 0):

I think the property you want (assuming I understood your question) is HttpContext.Current.Request.**RequestType**.  If you wanted Json you could do:

```
 var rType = new { Method = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestType };
 var thing = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rType);
```